# RxJs - Flat nested swithMaps and pass variables on Http interceptor

Tags: typescript, angular-2+, rxjs

How can the following method be flattened? I tried to pipe all the operators to the first pipe (from(`this.fireAuth.currentUser`)) but I lost access to the previous variables. It's an  Angular HTTP interceptor that adds a Bearer Token when the user has logged in, the chain should continue as usual when the user has not logged in yet.

```js
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const isApiUrl = request.url.startsWith(apiCloudURL);
    return from(this.fireAuth.currentUser).pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (!user) return next.handle(request);
        return from(user.getIdToken()).pipe(
          switchMap(token => {
            if (isApiUrl) request = this.addToken(request, token);
            return next.handle(request).pipe(
              catchError(error => {
                if ( isApiUrl && token && error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 403) {
                  return this.handle403Error(request, next);
                }
                else{
                  return throwError(error); 
                }
              })
            );
          })
        )
      })
    );
  }
```

Piping to the first observable... I have no access to the `token` var in the `catchError` block

```
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const isApiUrl = request.url.startsWith(apiCloudURL);
    return from(this.fireAuth.currentUser).pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (!user) return next.handle(request);
        return from(user.getIdToken());
      }),
      filter<string>(x => typeof(x) === "string"), //x can be string to HttpEvent<any>
      switchMap(token => {
        if (isApiUrl) request = this.addToken(request, token);
        return next.handle(request)
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        if ( isApiUrl && error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 403) {
          return this.handle403Error(request, next);
        }
        else{
          return throwError(error); 
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

I'm also wondering what's happening in the scenario where `user` is falsy, does it mean the request will be canceled because it does not pass the `filter`?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your specific example can be simplified by treating the non-observables as simple variables, eg:

```
intercept(
  request: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
  const user = this.fireAuth.currentUser; 
  if (!user) return next.handle(request);

  const isApiUrl = request.url.startsWith(apiCloudURL);
  const token = user.getIdToken();

  if (isApiUrl) request = this.addToken(request, token);
  
  return next.handle(request).pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      if ( isApiUrl && 
            token && 
            error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && 
            error.status === 403) {
        return this.handle403Error(request, next);
      } else {
        return throwError(error); 
      }
    })
  )
}
```

However, in the general case your question uncovers a couple of interesting RxJS "patterns".

First let's ignore the path where there is no user.  What you end up with is a sequence of requests (ie your switchMaps), *but* where the result of any earlier request is any later request.  There is no completely clean solution to this in standard RxJS - a number of options are discussed in this article [Aggregating RxJS Requests](https://thisisuntapped.com/articles/aggregating-rxjs-requests.html).  Nesting is the most common solution, which was your starting point.

I have been involved in the implementation of [a utility](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-concat-join) to address this scenario.

With your example the resultant code would be:

```
intercept(
  request: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
  const isApiUrl = request.url.startsWith(apiCloudURL);

  return concatJoin(
    from(this.fireAuth.currentUser),
    ([user]) => from(user.getIdToken),
    ([user, token]) => {
      if (isApiUrl) request = this.addToken(request, token);
      return next.handle(request).pipe(...),
    },
  ).pipe(
    // resultant value is [user, token, result] - we just want the result
    map([,,result]) => result
  );
}
```

Now returning to handle the case where there is no user, in your implementation you are right, the filter would cause it to never emit a value.  There has to be a level of nesting:

```
intercept(
  request: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
  const isApiUrl = request.url.startsWith(apiCloudURL);

  return from(this.fireAuth.currentUser).pipe(
    switchMap(user => {  // or use the iif operator
      if (!user) return next.handle(request);

      return concatJoin(
        (from(user.getIdToken),
        ([token]) => {
          if (isApiUrl) request = this.addToken(request, token);
          return next.handle(request).pipe(...),
        },
      ).pipe(
        // resultant value is [token, result] - we just want the result
        map([,result]) => result
      );

    )
  )    
}
```